Error Creating PostgreSQL Database in Discourse Development Environment
I'm facing issues while trying to create a PostgreSQL database for a Discourse development environment.
When running sudo bundle exec rake db:create, I'm facing the following errors:
ianasystems@ianaSystemssMBP discourse % sudo bundle exec rake db:create Deprecation notice: Array types for custom fields are deprecated, use type :json instead (removal in Discourse 3.3.0)  At /Users/ianasystems/discourse/lib/plugin/instance.rb:586:in block in register_topic_custom_field_typeDeprecation notice: Array types for custom fields are deprecated, use type :json instead (removal in Discourse 3.3.0)  At /Users/ianasystems/discourse/lib/plugin/instance.rb:586:inblock in register_topic_custom_field_typeDeprecation notice: Array types for custom fields are deprecated, use type :json instead (removal in Discourse 3.3.0)  At /Users/ianasystems/discourse/lib/plugin/instance.rb:607:inblock in register_user_custom_field_typeDeprecation notice: Array types for custom fields are deprecated, use type :json instead (removal in Discourse 3.3.0)  At /Users/ianasystems/discourse/lib/plugin/instance.rb:593:inblock in register_post_custom_field_typeconnection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied Couldn't create 'discourse_development' database. Please check your configuration. rake aborted! ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished) /Users/ianasystems/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/bundle:25:inload'
/Users/ianasystems/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/bundle:25:in `'
Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)
/Users/ianasystems/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/bundle:25:in load' /Users/ianasystems/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/bundle:25:in '
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
ianasystems@ianaSystemssMBP discourse % `
PostgreSQL server is running.
Redis is running.
I attempted to create a PostgreSQL database for Discourse development environment using sudo bundle exec rake db:create.
I expected the database creation process to succeed without errors. However, I received the error message fe_sendauth: no password supplied. This suggests a failure in the database connection due to a missing password.
